# Android AES Encrypted value does not match with Crypto.js AES encrypted value

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Hi i am using Java AES encryption for encrypting some values, and using following code for encryption:

```
public  String encrypt(String plain, String skey) {
        try {
            
            byte[] iv  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] ivAndCipherText = getCombinedArray(iv, cipherText);

           return Base64.encodeToString(ivAndCipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e);
            return null;
        }

    }


private static byte[] getCombinedArray(byte[] one, byte[] two) {
        byte[] combined = new byte[one.length + two.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; ++i) {
            combined[i] = i < one.length ? one[i] : two[i - one.length];
        }
        return combined;
    }
```

At server end i am using CryptoJS AES encryption / decryption. The string before encrypted in java AES and after decrypted using CryptoJS AES does not match . Please help me in finding the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Include your CryptoJS code and an example of encryption input/output.

Comment: Your initialization vector (`iv`) is random. How do you achieve an identical vector in your CryptoJS approach?

Comment: And to clarify @codebod, the IV being random is a good thing.  It doesn't matter if your ciphertexts match or not, the point is that they can both be decrypted and result in the same plaintext.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought the question is that the ciphertexts resulting from the 2 different libraries don't match, which would be expected if the ivs differed.

Comment: Please clarify your question _The encrypted string in java does not match with CryptoJs string._ Is there a problem with the decryption (not the expected clear text, errors) or is it not clear why you get two different ciphertexts? Also include all code (JS code). It'd be also helpful to have a specific example.